# Create developer certificate on windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-5, dotnet-dev-certs

I just tried creating a trusted developer certificate on my local machine (Windows 10).
I follow the below listed commands.

Frist to verify any certs exists.

```
C:\>dotnet dev-certs https --check
No valid certificate found.
```

Then I create the trusted certificate:

```
C:\>dotnet dev-certs https --trust
Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.
The HTTPS developer certificate was generated successfully.
```

I clicked on the prompt to trust the certificate.

Then I ran the following command to verify the created certificate on the machine

```
C:\>dotnet dev-certs https --check
No valid certificate found.
```

Looks like the certificate has not been created.

Has anyone experianced the same? Any fix or workaround for this?

Any thoughts?

Thanks
~RSF

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue today.

I had to:

1. Close all browsers. I closed VS Code to be safe also.
2. Remove all of the certificates for my Windows current user in the certificate store.
3. dotnet dev-certs https --clean
4. dotnet dev-certs https --trust
5. dotnet dev-certs https --check

I did that based upon [Windows - certificate not trusted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#windows---certificate-not-trusted-1)

Comment: Ensure you open the USER certificate store. Not the COMPUTER certificate store.